# Setting a number of bits based on a number (JS)

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a simple IP calculator, and I need a certain function in JavaScript I can't wrap my head around.

Based on a decimal number, it would create a number with amount of bits equal to said number.

For example - number 3 would create 0000 0111, number 7 would create 0111 1111, etc.

Comment: You need to recursively do a 2^x operation based on the number. E.g for the number 7 you need an algorithm that does 2^7 + 2^6 + 2^5 ... 2^1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use following code:

```js
function createSequence( ones, total ) {
  var result = (2**total + 2**ones - 1).toString(2).slice(1);
  console.log(result)
  return result;
}

createSequence( 3, 8 );
createSequence( 7, 8 )
```

Explanation:

`2**total`'s binary representation is 1 and `total` times 0 (for `total=8` 100000000)

`2**ones - 1`'s binary representation is 1 repeated `ones` times (for `ones=3` 111)

If you sum these numbers you have to remove leading 1

Note: if your browser doesn't support `**` operator you can use bit shifts:

```js
function createSequence( ones, total ) {
  var result = ((1<<total) + (1<<ones) - 1).toString(2).slice(1);
  console.log(result)
  return result;
}

createSequence( 3, 8 );
createSequence( 7, 8 )
```

Comment: Thank you, that's the exact thing I needed!

Answer (score 1):

As you have leading zeros, I assume the result is to be intended as a String. You could abuse [`Array.fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) for that:

```
function createSequence( ones, total ) {
  // create an array of the correct size
  return (new Array( total ))
  // add the zeros at the start
           .fill( 0, 0, total - ones )
  // add the ones at the end
           .fill( 1, total - ones )
  // stitch it all together
           .join( '' );
}

createSequence( 3, 8 );
// > "00000111"

createSequence( 7, 8 );
// > "01111111"
```

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
    NumberToBits(int x) {
    var answer = 2^x;
    if(x > 1)
        return answer + NumberToBits(x-1);
    }
```